# Add different JLists to cell renderer in JTable

Tags: java, swing

I'm able to create a JTable with cells rendered to use JList. What I don't know to do is to create different lists to add to cells.

This is my code right now

```
Vector<String> categoryReportColumnNames = new Vector<>();
    categoryReportColumnNames.add("Categorías");
    categoryReportColumnNames.add("Ítems");
    Vector<Vector<String>> categoryReportVector = controller.getCategoryReportVector();
    VectorTableCellRenderer renderer = new VectorTableCellRenderer();
    DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(categoryReportVector, categoryReportColumnNames);        
    jCategoryReportTable.setModel(tableModel);
    jCategoryReportTable.setEnabled(false);

    for (int i = 0 ; i < categoryReportVector.size() ; i++){
        Vector<String> categoryItems = controller.getCategoryItems(i);
        renderer.setListData(categoryItems);
        jCategoryReportTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).setCellRenderer(renderer);
    }

    jCategoryReport.setVisible(true);
```

Where should I send a Vector, for example, to change JList items for each row?

Thanks

Comment: can you add code of the controller too?

Comment: controller.getCategoryReportVector(); and controller.getCategoryItems(i);  code required

Comment: There's a few ways you could do it. See [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more details.  One way is to have the `TableModel` return the `Class` type for each given column and then setup default renders for that `Class` type

Comment: What are you think about following answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can do better way as follows. You should not set the renderer within a loop. Only thing you should create the data vector correctly.

**Modifications of your code**

```
    //create table columns
    Vector<String> categoryReportColumnNames = new Vector<>();
    categoryReportColumnNames.add("Categorías");
    categoryReportColumnNames.add("Ítems");

    //create table data
    Vector<Vector> categoryReportVector = controller.getDataVector();

    //setting the tabel model
    DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(categoryReportVector, categoryReportColumnNames);
    jCategoryReportTable.setModel(tableModel);

    //setting the table renderer
    VectorTableCellRenderer renderer = new VectorTableCellRenderer();
    jCategoryReportTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellRenderer(renderer);

    //additional modifications
    jCategoryReportTable.setEnabled(false);
    jCategoryReportTable.setRowHeight(100);
```

**Create Data Vector as follows.**

Use loops and create your own code referring this

```
    public Vector<Vector> getDataVector() {
        Vector rowOne = new Vector<String>();
        rowOne.add("Row1-Column1");
        Vector rowOneCategories = new Vector();
        rowOneCategories.add("Row1-Column2-Line1");
        rowOneCategories.add("Row1-Column2-Line2");
        rowOneCategories.add("Row1-Column2-Line3");
        rowOne.add(rowOneCategories);

        Vector rowTwo = new Vector<String>();
        rowTwo.add("Row2-Column1");
        Vector rowTwoCategories = new Vector();
        rowTwoCategories.add("Row2-Column2-Line1");
        rowTwoCategories.add("Row2-Column2-Line2");
        rowTwoCategories.add("Row2-Column2-Line3");
        rowTwo.add(rowTwoCategories);

        Vector<Vector> rowData = new Vector<Vector>();
        rowData.add(rowOne);
        rowData.add(rowTwo);

        return rowData;
    }
```